# .htaccess: Redirect 301 conflict with rewriterule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I recently updated an old website and I want to 301 all the old pages to the new version of each of them.

Here is my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

#
# below are the 301 redirects
# **rules**

#
# below are the RewriteCond
# **rules**

#
# other stuff
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that some of the old link are with the extension declared `oldfile.html`, others are just folders `oldfolder/`.

On the new version there are `products`, `products/category` and `products/category/subcategory`. These urls are generated with `RewriteCond`.

The following rule works:

```
Redirect 301 /category/ /products/category
```

The following does not work and instead redirects me to the home page.

```
Redirect 301 /old-folder/subcategory.html /products/category/subcategory 
# /products/category/subcategory is also a RewriteRule
```

Here is the exact code in the `.htaccess`

```
# 301 rule
Redirect 301 /arredo-urbano/blocchi-standard.html /prodotti/arredo-urbano/001-blocchi-standard
# RewriteRule
RewriteRule ^prodotti/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ prodotti.php?category=$1&subcategory=$2 [L]
```

I tried adding the `[L]` flag after each `Redirect 301` so the rest of the .htaccess is ignored, but this causes a `500 Internal Error`

All redirects are manually declared, with no regular expressions or wildcards and they are all spelled correctly.

Is there a way of making all redirect work as intended ? Also the thing that I do not understand is why the `[L]` flag causes an internal error.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three recommendations about redirect rules in general:

1. Keep redirect rules before internal rewrite rules
2. Keep specific patterns matching rules before generic pattern matching rules
3. Don't mix `Redirect` (mod_alias) rules with `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) rules.

Try these rules in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^category/?$ /products/category [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^old-folder/subcategory\.html$ /products/category/subcategory [L,NC,R=301]
#
# below are the 301 redirects
# **rules**

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#
# below are the RewriteCond
# **rules**

#
# other stuff
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be working. I have to manually change all the rules now. Just a question: will this be the same as redirect ? Can I just use RewriteRule instead ? I am doing this mostly for seo because the old website has a very good rank and I don't want to lose it.

Comment: Yes `RewriteRule` with `R=301` is same as `Redirect` but with more features